# Verify Lagrange's Mean Value Theorem for $f(x)=4-(6-x)^{\frac23}$ on $[5,7]$

Tags: derivatives

$f(x)=4-(6-x)^{\frac23}$

Well, $f(5)=3, f(7)=3$, so, $\frac{f(7)-f(5)}{7-5}=0$

And $f'(x)= \frac23 (6-x)^{-\frac13}$

So, by MVT, $\exists c\in (5,7)$ such that $\frac{f(7)-f(5)}{7-5}=f'(c)$,

i.e. $\frac23 (6-c)^{-\frac13}=0$, which doesn't yield any solution.

Where did I go wrong?

Note: One possibility that comes to my mind is that the conditions of MVT are not satisfied here, but if so, I cannot identify that. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function is continuous in [5,7], but it is not differentiable for x=6, which belongs to that interval, so you cannot apply the Mean value theorem